# Why do some people physically cover their macbook cameras

Tags: input, security, human-interface-guideline

Obviously, if a malicious user could save camera snapshots or streams you have a bigger issue on your hands than improperly lighted selfies. Or do they simply not get this / this isn't as commonly known as the fact that people could turn on the camera but not the little green light?

Why does the user *feel* more secure by simply taping paper over it. Why don't they shove blu tack in the microphone(s) etc.?

To summarise: why is the experience of opening the screen off putting to some when the camera is pointing directly at them (with no way of independently diverting it)

Comment: This question appears to be off topic and might be better suited for http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://www.ted.com/talks/christopher_soghoian_government_surveillance_this_is_just_the_beginning a nice talk about the same topic ;)

Comment: The answer is another question: Why do people have curtains in their windows?

Comment: also, the "Hacker" can programmatically turn off the green LED so the user could still be recorded regardless of that indicator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feedback and control. The physical obstruction of light to enter the camera ensures the user that it won't record anything. Software can't be seen, so what happens "under the hood" (especially if the user suspects that some malware might be running in the background) is hard to control. The physical world is, however, easier in this case.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense; but why specifically are they afraid of light - someone could be recording them through every peripheral connected to their computer. But they don't stop typing keystrokes, or obstruct their microphones - could we conjecture as to why?

Comment: People are very, very rarely this rational. You look at the screen, you see this 'eye' peeping back at you. It's actually quite intimidating on a subconscious level. The microphone, on the other hand, is invisible, and keystrokes are a requirement to use the computer.

Comment: Another point to ponder: What is more suitable for blackmail, a mute video of something or the mere sound? Yes, there are cases where the sound is the kicker, but in general "being watched" is causing more uneasiness than being eavesdropped on. After all you can just shut up, you cannot just vanish. And voyeurs will most likely be more interested in video than audio.

Comment: The average human out in society don't have that much to hide regarding conversations, but few of us wants to be seen in a our underwear surfing youtube - or worse, any color variation of that web page :D

Comment: +1 There is nothing as sure as making something physically impossible...

Comment: There's a reason why people sometimes unplug their internet (LAN) cable from the computer when they want to be sure that it can't reach the internet - the reason is the same as stated above...

Comment: I work at home. I'm fine hearing people listening to me talk, but I'm not about to start wearing pants!

Comment: @DA01 TMI, IMO (and I hope you don't mean 'pants' in the British sense ...)